# Sequencias de ações em ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Boa tarde! Não sei se o título da minha pergunta está correto mais se alguém tiver um melhor por favor troque.

Estou com seguinte problema, tenho um ERP de emissão e NFE e NFCe está funcionando corretamente, mais queria melhorar um pouco.

Eu utiliza Ajax para assinar e validar, enviar para SEFAZ e Consultar recibo.

Atualmente isso é feito por etapa, etapa um assina e validar, enviar, e consultar e imprimir.

Para cada evento preciso clicar no botão.

Teria como eu fazer isso no lado do servidor, exemplo faço um requisição Ajax, no lado do servidor eu faça uma ação aguarde uns 5 segundos e já inicie um outra, até finalizar e se possível ir avisando o usuário do que está acontecendo no sistema. Acho que seria isso.

Muito grato a todos, um grande abraço.

Comment: Acredito que seja possível sim, é só você ir pegando o retorno de cada chamada AJAX e executar o próximo AJAX. Você pode aproveitar também o retorno e atualizar a tela do usuário informando que mais um passo foi finalizado.

Comment: Creio que você pode fazer dentro da requisição, quando retornar `success`, você chama a próxima etapa e emite um aviso, e pula pra seguinte.

Comment: É eu pensei como vocês mais achei que teria uma forma diferente pra não ficar repetindo a requisição ajax toda hora.